# Visual Studio reformats my pre-formatted HTML

Tags: html, visual-studio, formatting

When I put text directly into a `<pre>` tag and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, the whitespace is preserved.

```
<pre>
  This
    whitespace
      gets
        preserved.</pre>
```

But when I put text in a tag nested within a `<pre>` tag, the whitespace is not preserved.

```
<pre><code>This whitespace doesn't get preserved.</code></pre>
```

Only text directly within the `<pre>` tag gets preserved.

```
<pre>
  This
    does,
      <code>but this doesn't,</code>
            and
              this
                does.</pre>
```

I've tried using the CSS white-space property...

```
<pre><code style="white-space:pre;">but it doesn't work either.</code></pre>
```

I've tried Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Formatting > Tag Specific Options, but there's nothing there that determines whether tags preserve whitespace.

It looks like this behavior is hard-coded into Visual Studio 2008/2010, but maybe one of you knows a workaround. Thanks.

A couple more things:

- I would prefer a valid XHTML/HTML5 solution
- I need to nest tags within `<pre>` tags (like `<a>` tags)

Comment: No idea. I often get frustrated with the way visual studio auto-formats things. Or more specifically, where it doesn't.

Comment: This is why VIM is such a better editor, its simple, doesn't do everything you don't want it to do.

Comment: Saying that vi/vim is a better IDE than Visual Studio is nothing but an admission that you don't know how to use Visual Studio.

Answer (score -2):

**Tool > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Miscellaneous [Format HTML on paste]**

The better question is why you're putting  tags inside  tags.

Comment: That doesn't work because I'm not pasting, I'm "formatting" the document. And as I said, I need to put anchor tags inside pre tags for hyperlinks.